# GoPro Hero 3 constant or variable frame rate?

Tags: gopro, framerate

Are the recordings of a GoPro Hero 3 camera at 60 fps with constant or variable frame rate? How can I check the corresponding mp4 file for constant or variable frame rate?

Here is the output of the `ffmpeg -i` command:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/media/102GOPRO/GOPR0333.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
  Duration: 00:19:53.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15122 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14982 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-16 13:18:14
      timecode        : 13:17:26:44
```

Comment: I vote to close this question because it is a video question and not a photo question. It should be moved to video.stackexchange

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The user manual of the [GoPro Hero 3](https://gopro.com/content/dam/help/hero3-white-edition/manuals/UM_H3White_ENG_REVB_WEB.pdf) doesn't mention anything about a variable frame rate. Based on the manual, I'd assume that the 720p video is 60fps, constant.

To check the frame rate of a video file you can use the free command line tool [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) like this:

```
ffmpeg -i <filename>
```

Comment: I have added the output of the command in my post. Is it constant frame rate?

Comment: @machinery yes it is. The relevant part is `59.94 fps` in the video track details. This is the NTSC standard framerate. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC#Lines_and_refresh_rate)

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin My bad. Didn't realize that the question is off-topic.